# WKinterfacePicker item issue

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a `WKInterfacePicker` in my Watch's Interface and want to add items to it. Here is my code I currently have:

```
let item1:WKPickerItem = WKPickerItem()
item1.title = "1"

let item2:WKPickerItem = WKPickerItem()
item2.title = "2"

timePicker.setItems([item1, item2])
```

When I run the app it crashes and tells me there is a nil last line:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

I had a look at Apple's docs for the [`WKInterfacePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfacePicker_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfacePicker/setItems:) and [`WKPickerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKPickerItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKPickerItem) but that did not help me either. Is it possible that I have to set the content of the items somehow else? I thought the title is the content already and I couldn't find any other method for setting content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that `timePicker` is nil. Did you remember to hook it up to the outlet?

```
@IBOutlet var timePicker: WKInterfacePicker!
```

Since it's declared with `!`, this is the only place you could be force unwrapping nil.

If you're still having problems, there's a full guide on WKInterfacePicker you can try here: http://www.sneakycrab.com/blog/2015/6/12/wkinterfacepicker-in-watchkit-20-using-the-digital-crown

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am using an `IBOutlet` just as you did. (Is there a way to add `WKInterfaceObject`s programmatically?) I'll check out the link.

Comment: Yes, but did you doublecheck that the IBOutlet is hooked up to your picker in the storyboard? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html
There's no way to add or remove `WKInterfaceObject` programmatically, but you can add all the ones you need in your storyboard, and use `setHidden` at runtime.

Comment: So I used that guide and did everything as they did but it still crashes because of a nil at the same line. Any idea?